# set number of elements for python block in gnu radio

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am having a Stream to Vector block which gives me 10 complex elements for another embedded block. How can I set the input type and length for my ambedded block to merge the size?
I have already tried the official suggested method:
in_sig = [(np.complex64,10)] 
but it doesn't work. I have attached a capture that shows how the my flowgraph should look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, but the problem was the gnu radio version.
I had this problem because of v3.7.10.1.
I am using 3.7.12.0 now and the solution  in_sig = [(np.complex64,10)] for the embedded python block works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Interleave` block together with a `Stream to Vector`. The last vector to stream is just for the proof that the stream has been merged in items of grouped 20 complex numbers.

[image]